# GCP Storage Bucket Access Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

If you set a storage bucket as a static website, is there any way to trace who has accessed it? e.g. IP addresses, time viewed etc...

I have looked in the stackdriver logs but it only shows events e.g. bucket created, files uploaded etc...

Comment: You could implement Google analitycs for example. A good and powerfull tool for track website usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to configure access logs for public buckets. Then you may import them into BigQuery for analysis.

Use Access and Storage logs if:

> - You want to track access to public objects, such as assets in a
>     bucket that you've  configured to be a static website.

You'll be able to get all the information required such as IP address, time, region, zone, headers, read/write ops etc. in the **access log fields.**

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Answer (score 2):

In GCP (of which GCS is a part), there is the concept of Audit Logs.  These are normally switched off by default and be can be enabled on a product by product basis.  For GCS, the Data Access Logs include DATA_READ which claims to log information on "getting object data".

**However**, before we go much further, there is a huge caveat.  It reads:

> Cloud Audit Logs does not track access to public objects.

What this means is that if you have exposed the objects as publicly readable (which is common for a WebSite hosted on GCS) then there are no logs captured.

References:

- [Cloud Audit Logs with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs)